# Python Selenium - StaleElementReferenceException

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I'm trying to scrape a website called iens with different webpages. Right now I'm able to scrape one page successfully.

My code thus far:

```
chrome_path = '/Users/username/Downloads/chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
url = 'https://www.iens.nl/restaurant'
pageExt = '#page='
restaurantList = []
cityList = ['utrecht']

def scrape(pageNumber):
    driver.get(url + '+' + cityList[0] + pageExt + str(pageNumber))
    items = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("resultItem-
    information")
    for item in items:
         restaurantList.append(item.text)
    return restaurantList

print scrape(14)
```

This gives me the results I need. However when I want to scrape more than one page like this:

```
print scrape(12)
print scrape(14)
```

I get the correct results for the data on webpage 12, but instead of getting the results for webpage 14 as well, I get the following error message:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: 
stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

The page is called https://www.iens.nl/restaurant+utrecht

Could you help me out?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This issue seem to reproduce randomly only once for each page. Could you try this code and let me know whether it works as expected:

```
import time

def scrape(pageNumber):
    driver.get(url + '+' + cityList[0] + pageExt + str(pageNumber))
    time.sleep(1)
    items = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("resultItem-information")
    for item in items:
        restaurantList.append(item.text)
```

Comment: I don't get an error any longer. The first line is still correct, but the second "scrape(number)" adds the same line as the first scrape to the restaurantList. So restaurantLine = [results from first page, results from first page]

Comment: If I use it up until range 10, page 2, 4 and 6 are missing btw!

Comment: As page for some reason could be randomly refreshed after `driver.get`, I add 1 second to wait. This seem to work now